# Legacy Bios PC - What all is required for a MBR hard drive to be bootable? Such as MBR, Boot Sector, Active Partition, Boot Loader, Ect

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning, uefi, mbr

Speaking about a traditional or "Legacy" BIOS based PC what is all required by the BIOS for the drive to be bootable without going into specific OSs requirements.

I know it needs to have a MBR and a active primary partition, but what else is checked?  Boot Sector?  Boot Loader?  BCD?

Comment: **All of the above.**

Comment: For Windows since Vista, "All of the above", as correctly pointed out.
For other systems, including Windows before Vista, if you want *some* compatibility, you need MBR (including MBR code and the 0x55AA mark at its end), one active partition, and a boot loader installed in the boot sector of that partition with the corresponding 0x55AA mark; what happens next depends entirely of that boot sector.
If you sacrifícate compatibility, the 0x55AA mark at the end of the LBA0 sector (which holds the MBR code) is the only thing checked. Most non-Windows loaders can do without an active partition.